# Hyperledger Indy LibIndy Installation Issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ubuntu-18.04, libsodium, hyperledger-indy

My development environment is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have cloned the Indy SDK from the GitHub repository. When I am trying to install libindy which is essential for Indy node and Indy pool, it is failing due to the non-availability of Libsodium18. I have already installed libsodium-dev on my machine. I have also installed libsodium23. It seems libdsodium23 is recommended for Ubuntu 18.04. Can anyone help me to find a solution or workaround so that I can setup Indy node and Indy Pool with libindy in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution here?
You could use a previous version of libindy. eg apt-get install -y libindy=1.14.2~1524

Comment: That's a good workaround. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Crazy man! @Polem It works!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y indy-cli
```